# Number of ordered set partitions, where each partition can also have one of n labels

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I have encountered a counting problem which involves counting all ordered partitions, where each partition can also have one of n labels.

For example: Given a set of two elements {A,B} with a single label L, there are two partitions, {L{A,B}} and {L{A},L{B}}, but there are four ordered partitions, (L{A,B}), (L{B,A}), (L{A},L{B}), and (L{B},L{A}).

If we have 2 possible labels X and Y, we now have the following possible labeled ordered partitions:
X:{A,B}
Y:{A,B}
X:{B,A}
Y:{B,A}
X{A},X{B}
X{A},Y{B}
Y{A},X{B}
Y{A},Y{B}
X{B},X{A}
X{B},Y{A}
Y{B},X{A}
Y{B},Y{A}

Are there closed formulas for this problem? Is this problem well studied in combinatorics? Are asymptotic formulas known?

I am happy for any advice or reference I can get.

Comment: Are you looking for compositions? They have closed form solutions. Actually one of the questions I asked is about this sadly no one has answered :P https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)

Comment: What is mean by the term "lebel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you have in mind is not an ordered partition, because your subsets have interior orders; it's really an ordered list of labelled disjoint tuples on the given set. So you can express the list as a permutation of the set with a label added next to the last element of each tuple.

Suppose the given set has ten elements, $\{0,1,\ldots 9\}$, and we have decided to use four labels. Write down one of the $10!$ permutations of this set. Now, after each element, either write a label, or a comma. The comma is effectively a fifth label. The last element, however, must have one of the four real labels. Thus the number of possibilities is $10!\cdot5^9\cdot4$.

Similarly, the number of possibilities on a set of $n$ elements and a set of $L$ labels is $$n!L(1+L)^{n-1}$$